# Can anyone tell me why is my code showing the wrong value of pi?

Tags: python, pi

[image: This is the equation i'm trying to use in the while loop]Here's a picture of my output:

[image]

```
inptTol = float(input("Enter the tolerance: "))
print()

term = 1
divNum = 3
npower = 1
sumPi = 0.0
count = 0

while abs(term) > inptTol:
    sumPi += term
    term = -term/(divNum * (3**npower))
    divNum += 2
    npower += 1
    count += 1

sumPi = math.sqrt(12) * sumPi  
pythonPi = math.pi  
approxError = abs (sumPi - pythonPi)  

print("The approximate value of pi is %.14e\n" \
        "       Python's value of pi is %.14e\n"
        "The error in the approximation of pi is %.6e\n"
        "The number of terms used to calculate the value of pi is %g " %
        (sumPi, pythonPi, approxError, count))
```

These are the values it is is showing:

The approximate value of pi is 3.08770957930231e+00

Python's value of pi is 3.14159265358979e+00

I want it to show me this :

The approximate value of pi is 3.14159265358979

Python's value of pi is 3.14159265358979

Comment: Try `print(str(yourNumber)[:-4])`

Comment: what value for `inptTol` did you use ? maybe use smaller.

Comment: Are you certain that the series that you are using converges to pi?  Do you have a reference for this series?  I don't remember seeing a formula like that before.

Comment: your calculation use only 7 terms - maybe use `for` loop instead of `inptTol` to use more terms in calculations.

Comment: i just added the screenshot for the series. @Matthew

Comment: yeah i could have used for but i want it with while. i just can't figure out the bug in the while loop. may be my relationship is faulty between the terms. @furas

Comment: `term = -term/(divNum * (3**npower))` here is the problem. You implemented sequence wrong.

Comment: put a `print(term)` right before `sumPi += term` you will see that your series is not being calculated correctly.

Comment: Ok, I have seen that before.  I was having a hard time extracting it from your code.  With the corrections suggested in the answers, you can make this work.  However, if you are concerned about accuracy (or more digits), it is best to not use the built in float format (or double or anything else), but to either use a fixed precision class, or write your own code to keep track of digits (which is, of course, significantly more work), because eventually you will hit the limitations of such systems.  I myself have wrote code to compute pi using Machin's formula storing the digits in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me problem is because you change `term` value. it has to be `1` or `-1` - sign.

My version - I use `for` loop

```
import math

terms_number = float(input("Enter terms number: "))

sign = 1
divNum = 1
npower = 0
sumPi = 0.0
count = 0

for x in range(terms_number):

    sumPi += sign/(divNum * (3**npower))

    # values for next term
    sign = -sign
    divNum += 2
    npower += 1
    count += 1


sumPi = math.sqrt(12) * sumPi  
pythonPi = math.pi  
approxError = abs (sumPi - pythonPi)  

print("The approximate value of pi is %.14e\n" \
        "       Python's value of pi is %.14e\n"
        "The error in the approximation of pi is %.6e\n"
        "The number of terms used to calculate the value of pi is %g " %
        (sumPi, pythonPi, approxError, count))
```

Result for 7 terms

```
The approximate value of pi is 3.14167431269884e+00
       Python's value of pi is 3.14159265358979e+00
The error in the approximation of pi is 8.165911e-05
The number of terms used to calculate the value of pi is 7
```

Result for 15 terms

```
The approximate value of pi is 3.14159265952171e+00
       Python's value of pi is 3.14159265358979e+00
The error in the approximation of pi is 5.931921e-09
The number of terms used to calculate the value of pi is 15
```

---

**EDIT:** version with your `while` loop

```
import math

inptTol = float(input("Enter the tolerance: "))
term = 1

sign = 1
divNum = 1
npower = 0
sumPi = 0.0
count = 0

while abs(term) > inptTol:

    term = sign/(divNum * (3**npower))

    sumPi += term

    # values for next term
    sign = -sign
    divNum += 2
    npower += 1
    count += 1


sumPi = math.sqrt(12) * sumPi  
pythonPi = math.pi  
approxError = abs (sumPi - pythonPi)  

print("The approximate value of pi is %.14e\n" \
        "       Python's value of pi is %.14e\n"
        "The error in the approximation of pi is %.6e\n"
        "The number of terms used to calculate the value of pi is %g " %
        (sumPi, pythonPi, approxError, count))
```

Comment: I'm still using while loop but changed my loop to yours and I'm not getting anything at all.                                                                                            while abs(term) > inptTol:
    sumPi += term/(divNum * (3**npower))
    term = -term
#    term = -term/(divNum * (3**npower))
    divNum += 2
    npower += 1
    count += 1

Comment: because `term` is always 1 or -1 so you can't use it in `abs(term) > inptTol`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing `signal`. Apparently you tried to do this but changing the previous term signal and using it on the next term.
See my code, i tried to do like his. What do you think?

```
import math
inptTol = float(input("The tolerance: "))

signal = 1.0
term = 1.0
divNum = 3.0
npower = 1.0
sumPi = 0.0
count = 0.0

while inptTol < abs(term):
    signal *= -1.0
    sumPi += term
    term = signal / (divNum * (3.0 ** npower))
    divNum += 2.0
    npower += 1.0
    count += 1.0

sumPi *= math.sqrt(12.0)
pythonPi = math.pi  
approxError = abs(sumPi - pythonPi)  

print("The approximate value of pi is %.14f\n" \
        "       Python's value of pi is %.14f\n"
        "The error in the approximation of pi is %.6e\n"
        "The number of terms used to calculate the value of pi is %g " %
        (sumPi, pythonPi, approxError, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `term` calculation is wrong:

```
term = -term/(divNum * (3**npower))
```

Say `term` is currently `-1/(3*3)`. This line won't set `term` to `1/(5 * 3**2)`; it'll set `term` to `1/(3*3) / (5 * 3**2)`. You're reducing `term` way more than you're supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to define `term[i+1]` in terms of `term[i]`. If you change that line to:

```
term = -term*(divNum-2)/(divNum * 3)
```

then the recursive definition will produce the appropriate values. This definition will flip the sign, remove the old odd number in the denominator, add the new odd number in the denominator, and add a factor of 3 in the denominator.

Comment: i did that and the value has gone to 9 sth. @o_o

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of pattern to generate the denominator for the terms in your approximation.  I'll let you do the division and summation, and the final multiplication by sqrt(12)

```
print [(-1)**(i%2)*(3**(i)*(1+i*2)) for i in range(0,10)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using `e` as the number format which means:

> Exponent notation. Prints the number in scientific notation using the letter ‘e’ to indicate the exponent.

If you want fixed point output you can use `f`:

> Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number.

Other formats/options can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

---

Found the bug in your code. Each `term` is calculated using the previous `term` as the numerator, when really you just want alternating -1 and 1s. Changing the formula for calculating `term` fixes the issue:

```
term = ((-1)**npower)/(divNum * (3**npower))
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/xfHxyw)

Comment: Oh I didn't realize the calculations were wrong. I thought you just wanted to get rid of the `e+00`, so this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: No my pi value is different than the python value. i did try f but it's not working. maybe something is wrong in the while loop @clcto